# Simulate key press events on a Mac using C# .Net Core

Tags: c#, macos, .net-core

I have a solution built in C# .Net Core 3.1.

When running in Windows I use the Windows Input Simulator package to simulate key presses, but what can I use on a Mac? I have scanned the net for answers but can't find anything about C# and .Net Core.

Please note that I'm not asking for a way to get Input Simulator/SendKeys/SendInput to work in Mac, I know it will not work. I'm looking for some other way to do the same thing in Mac. Something that works in C#. And .Net Core. And that can handle all kind of key presses (including Shift/Command/Option variations)